# ¿Alguien me explica para qué sirve return?

Tags: c#, return

Dejo esto, supuestamente es un chiste! Pero no lo comprendo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Un return es lo que devuelve algo al final de tu función. Por ejemplo, esa función que tienes recibe un numero, sí ese numero concuerda con alguno de tus `if` que tienes, te retorna un `false` y si no, lo devuelve como un `true`.

Comment: Hoa Franco, vamos por partes, en este sitio respondemos preguntas relacionadas con el arte de crear programas, no hacemos interpretación de chistes, te sugiero que elimines tu pregunta para evitar recibir votos negativos... el chiste tiene que ver con la forma de trabajar de algunas personas, hacen una función errónea, le envían un "11" y falla, entonces le agregan una linea que ante la entrada aludida, retorne el valor correspondiente, luego le envían, un "3", y vuelve a fallar, y así siguen metiendo parches.. y los documentan.

Comment: @Luis no exactamente. Puedes ver que en el código hay `return`s antes del final. Específicamente `return` termina la función, pudiendo regresar un valor también.

Comment: Pon el código como texto. De esa forma será más legible y se podrá copiar fácilmente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El chiste es que esos "parches" son para pasar los "test"; por el nombre de la función "isEven" se sabe que el creador del código queria determinar si un valor entero es "even" o es "odd" (pares on nones).

Al parecer tiene problemas en su función cuando la entrada se trata de los números 3, 11 , 11404 y 9, así que para que el test no retorne error cuando calcula para alguno de estos valores el amigo programador puso eso bloques de "if" y con el "return false" que lo que hace es terminar la ejecución del resto del code y así siempre devolver true o no devolver nada.

No sabemos bien cómo funciona la mente de un programador (aún siendo uno de ellos), y no somos capaces de comprender la eficacia de esta solución, pero su código pasó los test y es lo que importa.

Comment: Ayúdanos a mantener la calidad de la información en el sitio, respondiendo a preguntas realizadas de acuerdo a [ask] saludos.